# Jquery - on click not working on dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I have a cookie banner that is getting loaded into the DOM through JS and I am trying to add a click event to the close button on this banner.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
        console.log('click');
    });

});
```

Can anyone please advise how I get this click function to register? I don't see why the above code wouldn't be working. It works fine when I change the selector to an element that is loaded onto the page in the first instance and it works correctly, just doesn't like the dynamically loaded element?

EDIT:

Here's the full code:

```
function setBannerCookie(){
   if(typeof tealiumBanner.setBannerCookie === 'function'){
       tealiumBanner.setBannerCookie();
   }
}

function setBannerCookie() {

    jQuery.cookie ("mmmBanner", "accepted", {expires:365, path:"/"});
    jQuery("#cookieBox").animate({height:"toggle"}, 500);

    var optOutMultiCookie = jQuery.cookie("OPTOUTMULTI");

    var cookieArray = optOutMultiCookie.split('|');

    for(var i=0;i<cookieArray.length;i++){
        var itemArray = cookieArray[i].split(':');
        newItem = itemArray[0] + ":0";
        cookieArray[i] = newItem;
    }

    cd = new Date();
    cd.setDate(cd.getDate() + 90);
    document.cookie = 'OPTOUTMULTI=' + cookieArray.join("|") + ';path=/;domain=' + utag.cfg.domain + ';expires=' + cd.toGMTString() + ";";
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if (jQuery.cookie("mmmBanner") == undefined) {
        jQuery.cookie ("mmmBanner", "waiting", {expires:365, path:"/"});
    }

    jQuery("#mmmCorpCookie").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (typeof __tealiumMo2Div == 'undefined') {__tealiumMo2Div = document.createElement('SCRIPT');__tealiumMo2Div.type = 'text/javascript';__tealiumMo2Div.src = '//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/3m/offp-it-it/prod/utag.tagsOptOut.js?cb='+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(__tealiumMo2Div);}else{__tealium.load();}
    });
    if (jQuery.cookie("mmmBanner") == undefined) {

        jQuery.cookie ("mmmBanner", "waiting", {expires:365, path:"/"});
    }
    if (jQuery.cookie("mmmBanner") === "waiting") {
        (function () {if (typeof __tealiumMo2Div == 'undefined') {__tealiumMo2Div = document.createElement('SCRIPT');__tealiumMo2Div.type = 'text/javascript';__tealiumMo2Div.src = '//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/3m/offp-it-it/prod/utag.tagsOptOut.js?_cb='+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(__tealiumMo2Div);}else{__tealium.load();}})();
    }

});



/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function encode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : encodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function decode(s) {
        return config.raw ? s : decodeURIComponent(s);
    }

    function stringifyCookieValue(value) {
        return encode(config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value));
    }

    function parseCookieValue(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }

        try {
            // Replace server-side written pluses with spaces.
            // If we can't decode the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            // If we can't parse the cookie, ignore it, it's unusable.
            s = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    function read(s, converter) {
        var value = config.raw ? s : parseCookieValue(s);
        return $.isFunction(converter) ? converter(value) : value;
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // Write

        if (value !== undefined && !$.isFunction(value)) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setTime(+t + days * 864e+5);
            }

            return (document.cookie = [
                encode(key), '=', stringifyCookieValue(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // Read

        var result = key ? undefined : {};

        // To prevent the for loop in the first place assign an empty array
        // in case there are no cookies at all. Also prevents odd result when
        // calling $.cookie().
        var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];

        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = parts.join('=');

            if (key && key === name) {
                // If second argument (value) is a function it's a converter...
                result = read(cookie, value);
                break;
            }

            // Prevent storing a cookie that we couldn't decode.
            if (!key && (cookie = read(cookie)) !== undefined) {
                result[name] = cookie;
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
        $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
        return !$.cookie(key);
    };

}));

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to register this event just after you append your dynamically created control to page.

Comment: Make sure `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` is added to your page before register `click` event

Comment: It is clear that you are attached the event click before the element already exists, try to attach it just after the element is loaded and not the document.

Comment: @ArunKumar no, using `.on('click')` will work for dynamically added elements

Comment: The body should have rendered prior to the document ready event handler fires thus, attaching the event handler to the body should be fine.  There is something else at play here.  Can you post the HTML so we can cross check stuff like spelling, class attributes etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This code is the last thing that gets loaded into the document before my closing body tag. I've also tried jQuery(window).load(function () {}; instead of document ready :/

Comment: @heady12 can you share how do you load the banner?

Comment: Hi @BrankVictoria, I've added the full code that handles the banner in my post :)

Comment: Please provide the html too. Your javascript code works fine. You probably have invalid html or use different class.

Comment: Hi @MarkBaijens, I've checked and the .ui-dialog-titlebar-close class name is correct

Comment: Are you loading your banner using the following javascript file "tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/3m/offp-it-it/prod/utag.tagsOptOut.js"?

Comment: @BrankVictoria, Yeah its getting loaded by 3rd party JS. I've managed to get it working on other elements within the cookie banner but doesn't work in the close anchor. Think there is something within the JS that prevents my event.

Comment: @heady, please provide the html output (trough inspect in the browser), or even better if possible a snippet that reproduces the problem. Check if the html is not in an iFrame or something. W3 also has html validators where you can check for mistakes that brake the structure.

Answer (score 0):

removed it from
Jquery(document).ready it is not needed as your content is loading dynamically after page is already loaded.

Instead use following and put it just before `</body>`

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the click function still doesn't see to fire.

Comment: `jQuery('document')` should be `jQuery(document)`. But note use this for testing purpose only. You want to do event delegation on the closest static element.

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanx for pointing towards the mistake, I've updated my answer. Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks, removed the down vote. However I don't agree totally to the leaving it outside of the ready function, because normally (in production) you don't want to use `document` for delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are loading your banner using the javascript:

```
tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/3m/offp-it-it/prod/utag.tagsOptOut.js
```

Then you must attach the onclick method after the javascript is already loaded and executed, you can do this using the onloaded attribute for script html tag.

For example:

```
__tealiumMo2Div = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
__tealiumMo2Div.type = 'text/javascript';
__tealiumMo2Div.src = '//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/3m/offp-it-it/prod/utag.tagsOptOut.js?_cb='+Math.random();
__tealiumMo2Div.onload = function()
{
      jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
};

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(__tealiumMo2Div);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would temporize the onclick event by using setTimeout :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('body').on( 'click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
           console.log('click');
       });
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: In my opinion this is a very very bad practice, you will never know how much time will it take to load, in this case the banner. We should always have to avoid the settimeout except in the case that we don't have any other solution.